# JSON array iteration skips first element - NodeJS

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, setinterval, indexoutofboundsexception

Ive got this JSON markup:

```
"Categories": [
            {"name": "a", "id": "1"},
            {"name": "b", "id": "2"},
            {"name": "c", "id": "3"},
            {"name":"d", "id": "4"},
            {"name":"e", "id": "5"},
            {"name": "f", "id": "6"},
            {"name": "g", "id": "7"},
            {"name": "h", "id": "8"}
        ]
```

Ive got a setInterval going over each of these categories and making a new Promise for each one.

For some unknown reason, it always skips the first element and exists with an out of bounds exception

```
var i = 0;

    var id = setInterval(function(){
        if (i == categories.length){
            clearInterval(id);
        }

            client.itemSearch({  
              category: categories[i].id,
              catName: categories.name,
            }).then(function(results){
                console.log("From category - " + categories[i].name + "\n" +
                            "Title: " + results[0].Title);
            },function(err) {
                console.log("error at " + categories[i].name);
            });
            i+=1;
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're referencing `i` in your promise callbacks and `i` changes every second. So your callbacks are being executed sometime in the future when `i === categories.length`, which would be an invalid index.

Since you already have a closure, just store the current category object in a variable outside of your promise callbacks and reference that instead.

You're also letting the function continue when `i === categories.length` which will cause an invalid index access.

Here's an example of a solution that fixes the aforementioned issues:

```
var i = 0;
var id = setInterval(function() {
  if (i === categories.length) {
    clearInterval(id);
    return;
  }
  var category = categories[i];
  client.itemSearch({  
    category: category.id,
    catName: category.name,
  }).then(function(results) {
    console.log("From category - " + category.name + "\n" +
                "Title: " + results[0].Title);
  }, function(err) {
    console.log("error at " + category.name);
  });
  i += 1;
}, 1000);
```

Lastly, you originally had `catName: categories.name` but I changed it to `catName: category.name` as I assumed that may have been your original intention.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly it!